# Does all the citrus fruit contain Citric acid and Ascorbic acid?

Tags: biochemistry

While reading a sixth class book about acid bases and salts. I figured that that citrus fruits like lemon, orange etc.. contains **citric acid**. But in the same book they also given that amla contains **Ascorbic acid**. Amla being a citrus fruit should contain Citric acid. I am just confused with this.

> Just tell me whether all the citrus fruits contains both citric acid as well as ascorbic acid.

I checked in wikipedia & also in oxford dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: You might be interested in the [meaning of citrus](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/citrus).

Comment: It seems most of the fruits has citric acid! @another'Homosapien'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the colloquial/vernacular/etymological meaning of "citrus"; when it comes about scientific names; [*Citrus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrus) is a particular [genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus). It do have many species.

> "Amla being a citrus fruit"

No. Amla ([*Phyllanthus emblica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllanthus_emblica)) is not a member of genus Citrus; not even allied.

Ascorbic acid is just another name for Vitamin C. It is also present in common edible citrus fruits.